# Why isn't std::atomic_is_lock_free a static constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I am confused. How is it possible that implementation may know if type is atomic only at runtime?

Comment: Note the comments on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free) about aligned and mis-aligned objects.

Comment: There are also macros such as `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE` for basic types which you can check at compile time.

Comment: @Angew yeah, but I specifically asked for `std::atomic_is_lock_free()` instead of `std::atomic::is_lock_free()` (member function). `std::atomic_is_lock_free` knows only type. If type has bad alignment it is known at runtime.

Comment: @interjay yes, but if I for example want to use some `typedef`-ed type this won't work...

Comment: @GreenScape `std::atomic_is_lock_free` takes an instance pointer as parameter. It's the same as calling the member function.

Comment: @GreenScape Yes, you asked for `std::atomic_is_lock_free()`, and that's what I linked to.

Comment: @Angew, interjay: yeah, my bad, sorry, overlooked. I had an impression that it only needed type.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler may not know what CPU the code will run on, and CPUs may differ in their lock-free capabilities. For example, a CPU may not support atomic operations on `long` types (and so a lock may be needed), but if the system has only a single core, they may be atomic automatically because they can't be interrupted and there's no other core to race with (and so nothing special is needed and the type is lock free).

Comment: If the compiler would not know whether the CPU requires a lock or not, how could it guarantee that the generated code is data-race free?

Comment: @ComicSansMS At run time, it will decide whether to use locking code or lock-free code. I used to write code that did this all the time, back when single core systems were the norm.

Comment: I can see why one might want to do that in user code, but I would be quite surprised if a compiler generated code like this. But I can see how it would be a valid optimization in certain cases, if the compiler is able to generate code to detect the only-one-processor case reliably. Do you know of any compilers that actually do this?

Comment: I don't. But it wouldn't have to be the compiler, it could equally well be the standard library. I definitely know libraries that do this. I've written a few. (One case was supporting bugged Pentium Pro CPU's that mishandle some atomic operations by using locks instead.)

Comment: I see. Even though I think that [Angew's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845182/why-isnt-stdatomic-is-lock-free-a-static-constexpr#comment40437750_25845182) still makes the better answer to the original question, that's a really interesting case to consider. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: If CPU does not support atomic operations on `long` how will compiler check for that at runtime? As I see it atomic operation is just a single CPU instruction. How to detect at runtime it it's valid or no?

Comment: @GreenScape It depends on the details. It might, for example, ask the OS. It might use a specialized CPU instruction to detect the CPU's capabilities.